# String and memory

Tags: java, string

```
class A {



  public void someMethod() {
         String var = "Abhi";
         var = "Abhishek";
  }
}
```

Will the var variable store Abhi and Abhishek in different memory location or `Abhishek` overwrites `Abhi` ??

If i use this expression `String var= new String();`, then what?

Comment: It is syntactically incorrect to redeclare any variable in such a manner as `String var = "Abhi"; String var = "Abhishek";`

Comment: What are u trying to achieve?

Comment: If this compiled, I'd answer, but you have made no effort to ask a reasonable question.

Comment: The newly edited code **still** won't compile, because you can't have arbitrary statements (such as this assignment) in the method body.

Comment: @Bohemian I am extremely sorry Sir. I have edited my code please see

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given this method:

```
public void someMethod() {
    String var = "Abhi";
    var = "Abhishek";
}
```

In this example there are 3 relevant things:

- There's a *variable* called `var`. This variable is stored on the stack (because it's a local variable) and can hold the reference to some object.
- There's the *`String` object* with the content `Abhi`: it's the first thing that `var` references right after its declaration.
- There's the *`String` object* with the content `Abhishek`: `var` is modified to reference this object in the second line where `var` is mentioned.

So in respect to memory: the two *`String` objects* are stored in distinct spaces, unrelated to each other. `var` however, only ever occupies the same place (during a single invocation of `foo`, that is). So the *reference to `Abhi`* is overwritten with a *reference to `Abhishek`*.

If you add the line `var= new String();` at the end of that method, then that line would do two things:

1. create a new `String` object representing the empty `String` and
2. assign a reference to that new `String` object to the variable `var`.

Note that there is almost never a reason to use that `String` constructor, because `""` has (almost) the exact same effect.

Comment: WHOA.. how did I miss that? LOL Thanks. Sorry.

Comment: Joachim, maybe you could add a small section about the String pool to clarify the difference between var = new String() and var = ""?

Comment: @Adriaan: I'm not sure that it would help here. The OP seems to be asking about the relation of objects and variables and I tried to explain that. Explaining the string pool now would just add more information to grok that's not terribly important in this context.

Answer (score 1):

They will probably be distinct memory values.

Of course it is conceivable that some advanced JVM could implement this feature, but it is probably unlikely and I've never heard of such an optimization being used in a real compiler; especially considering that this a pretty low payoff optimization (you save a few bytes that would've otherwise been used to represent the shorter string), which requires some pretty special conditions to work (ie you have one string constant which is the prefix of another).

EDIT:  Corrected answer according to Jesper's comment.

Comment: Strings in Java are not stored as **null-terminated** character arrays.

Comment: Java does **not** use null terminated strings (and it's `String` objects are definitely *not* simple char-arrays).

Comment: @Jesper:  You are correct, I just fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the var variable store Abhi and Abhishek in different memory location or `Abhishek` overwrites `Abhi` ??

Neither. This code will not compile, because you are declaring two variables with the same name `var`.

If we look at this:

```
class A {
    public void someMethod {
        String var = "Abhi";
        var = "Abhishek";
    }
}
```

The second assignment to `var` will make `var` refer to a different `String` object.

Note that in Java, variables are *references* to objects - they do not represents objects directly (as in C++).

Answer (score 0):

Your new string will be put into new location in memory because it will be a new object, but don't worry... there is garbage collection mechanism in java so your old object memory will be restored right after that because there will be no reference for your old string object...

Comment: Except that `String` literals are not garbage collected - they are stored in the string pool and remain there until the JVM exits.

Comment: @Jesper: actually, that's not true (or at least no longer). Even interned `String` values can be GCed if they are not referenced anywhere else anymore.

Comment: @Joachim aha, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it is worth mentioning the immutability of String objects in Java. Specifically, in your example, even though you are overwriting the reference to the String that the variable `var` is referencing, the data itself is not being "overwritten".

Answer (score -1):

In Java, you can't define "var" twice.  It will not simply create a new memory location and throw a new instance of "var" in there. Our first step has to be fixing your code. Instead, your code will look like this:

```
  String var = "Abhi";
  var = "Abhishek";
```

Therefore, to answer your first question, yes. "Abhishek" will overwrite "Abhi".

If you use

```
String var= new String();
```

that means you create a new instance of the class String and you assign it to var. Var becomes a new, empty (I believe), string.

Comment: That will also not compile, because you cannot have an assignment statement like that at class level.

Comment: Whoops. You're right, I didn't notice that when I posted it. :D